# Função tapply - argumentos devem ter o mesmo comprimento

Tags: r

Olá, boa noite!

Tenho um data frame com milhares de linhas e 58 colunas contendo, por exemplo, fornecedor, material, quantidade de material e valor total do material. Fiz um exemplo abaixo, somente do que preciso neste primeiro momento.

```
Fornecedor  Material    Qtde    Valor_Total
A   A   1   100
A   B   2   150
A   E   5   26
B   B   6   76
C   A   5   126
C   C   1   58
D   D   10  108
E   E   9   99
E   A   7   30
E   E   8   80
E   E   1   54
F   G   1   0
```

Primeiro, eu criei uma coluna com o valor médio de cada linha

```
dados$valor_medio <- round(dados$Valor_Total/dados$Qtde,2)
```

Agora eu preciso calcular a média, mediana e uma nova média, tirando os *outliers*, de `dados$valor_medio` por material. Porém, quando aplico a função `tapply` ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
dados<-tapply(dados$valor_medio, dados$Material, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Error in tapply(dados$valor_medio, dados$Material, mean, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  argumentos devem ter o mesmo comprimento

Alguém poderia me ajudar com este erro e informar como calculo a média tirando os *outliers* de `dados$valor_medio` de cada material?

PS: O material é `chr`

Comment: Provavelmente sua coluna dados$Material é uma lista ou algo do tipo. Qual o resultado de `str(dados$Material)` ou `class(dados$Material)`?

Comment: com esse exemplo seu, eu consegui rodar sem erro nenhum

Comment: > class(base$Material)
[1] "character"

Comment: Na verdade, o Material tem o seguinte formato: 00.000.000. Fui infeliz no exemplo, desculpem.

Answer (score 2):

Quando dá esse erro, a maior parte das vezes é porque se deve usar `?ave` e não `tapply`.

```
dados$valor_medio <- round(dados$Valor_Total/dados$Qtde,2)

dados$media <- ave(dados$valor_medio, dados$Material, FUN = mean)
dados$mediana <- ave(dados$valor_medio, dados$Material, FUN = median)
```

Quanto à outra média, sem outliers, depende da definição de outliers. A sua definição é a usada pela função `boxplot.stats`, portanto vou chamar essa função para calcular a outra média.

```
media_sem_out <- function(x){
    s <- boxplot.stats(x)$stats
    x <- x[s[1] <= x & x <= s[5]]
    mean(x)
}

dados$media2 <- ave(dados$valor_medio, dados$Material, FUN = media_sem_out)
```

Comment: Vou considerar a média sem extremos como sendo a média dos valores entre o Limite Inferior e o Limite Superior do Box-Plot, ou seja, os valores entre (primeiro quartil - 1,5 * (terceiro quartil - primeiro quartil)) e (terceiro quartil + 1,5 * (terceiro quartil - primeiro quartil))